# How to download an asset (zip file) stored on Amazon S3 without having direct access to the bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a zip file stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.
I've found the location of the file in the site's javascript but if I just stick that in the address bar i get 'access denied'. 
The zip contains CAD models which are unzipped (presumably remotely) and visualized in a javascript 3D model viewer on the page when loaded.
I have to be logged-in in order to load the page, does this mean I can somehow get access to the zip file?

If it has any relevance, after the file's location URL is an AWSAccessKeyID, Signature and Expiry.

And if it wasn't already obvious, I have no coding experience but I'd really like some pointers if this is even possible.

Comment: That sounds like a [presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) from S3.  It's likely that the expiration is short and generated on the server side of the site you're accessing.  I would reach out to the site to see if they can provide you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been blindly messing about and have managed to download the zip file.

I just copied and pasted the javascript code that included the file location in the console. It started with 'JSON.parse' and hey presto a downloadable link appeared! I had no idea it would be so easy.